# iOS app not rendering correctly on Android 4.3

Tags: android, jquery, ios, rendering

I build an iOS app using Cordova and it renders as expected on any iOS device. Now I'm using the same framework jQuery for the Android version and when i run the Android simulator it renders completely different. As you can see from the screen shots. This is my first android app so I'm not sure if I should be coding differently. Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/daigevqmmhwttdc/iOS.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9p9ewqee68ty8b/Android.png

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to have the completely same behavior on all devices with HTML.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true. If the device has a Webkit browser it should render pretty close, the exception would be those Webkit browsers that have adapted all the CSS3 properties. I was able to get my hands on actual device running 4.3 and the apps renders the same as the ios, need some adjustments on the CSS but overall the same. Not sure why the emulator doesn't produce the same renderings.

Screen shots from an actual device:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/92y6qwm89qdgkn6/Android_23.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fkrdf0xxuimysy/Android_22.png

Answer (score 0):

They are not that much different really. Also users using Android may not expect the same look-and-feel as those using iOS and vice-versa. Do they really need to be identical?

Comment: The Android's UI is different, there is supposed to be a search field at the very top which you can see on the iOS but on the Android it looks to be hidden. When you search something on the app the results that are render are very different, take a look at these screen shots so you can see what I am referring to.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/li9ti1s98r3x0mp/iOS_2.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ey7wgaihkaj02d/Android_2.png